# Force My Sites Sync Of New AD Info

Tags: my-site, active-directory, people-search

So I have noticed that my My Sites profiles will sometimes be less accurate then my People Search in SharePoint. Is there a way to force My Sites to sync up with the new information in my Active Directory?

Comment: Do you have a full AD Import scheduled or any incremental imports scheduled?

Comment: Incremental is scheduled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest by PirateEric, I have tried to perform a full AD import. This has fixed my problem,  so I believe that I was just missing this step.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: Good to know it worked, but this could be a comment under the answer.

Comment: @BennySkogberg - Actually, since there isn't any other answer I have tried to savage this comment to be more answer like. user1901780, please - if this was the actual solution, could you please accept this post as an answer?

Comment: Sure... Sorry I'm not great at using this site.